# Meaning of "defined"

Tags: logic, terminology

What are the precise meanings of terms "*defined*", "*well defined*" and "*undefined*", etc.? We can't define what "defined" means since then we would run into circular definitions. (If definitiveness is established in terms of something else like "existence", then again we face the same problem.)

Comment: Is this really a question? It seems argumentative as currently phrased.

Comment: Short answer: we can define$_1$ what it means to define$_0$ something.

Comment: http://www.smbc-comics.com/comics/20101024after.gif

Comment: Here are some legitimate questions that may be lurking in the background: (1) What is the point of defining things in terms of other things?  (2) Does every term used in mathematics have to be defined in terms of other things? (3) What is the role of definitions in mathematics? (4) What is the role of definitions in mathematical logic? (5) What does "well-defined" mean when defining a function?

Comment: What do you mean by the word "mean"? What do you mean by the word "word"? What do you?

Comment: @Asaf Bill Clinton did it first :-)

Comment: @Trevor: I'm actually paying my homage to Michael Palin from the end of the Monty Python sketch "Mr. Hilter".

Comment: @Trevor: [See here](http://youtu.be/vlmGknvr_Pg?t=7m55s).

Comment: @Asaf Ah, I hadn't seen that one

Comment: My answer concerning "well defined" is more concrete and in some ways more explicit than is Carl Mummert's, so I hope you'll consider looking at it as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mathematics is not about what "define" means in English or a natural language - that is a subject for philosophy or for the study of language. But we can *use* natural language to explain what it means to define something in mathematics.

The most common type of definition in mathematics says that any object with a certain collection of properties is given a certain name. For example a polygon with three corners is named a triangle. These definitions are trivial in the sense that you could replace the defined word with its definition, and although it might be inconvenient there would be no formal loss of meaning.

The term *well defined* is used in some settings where we want to make a definition, but there is a worry that the "definition" is faulty. It is used most often when we define a function on an entire equivalence class by looking at a representative of the equivalence class; in this case we have to argue that the function gives the same value no matter which representative is chosen, and we then say that the function is "well defined".

Answer (score 4):

**"Well defined"** usually means **unambiguously defined**, which is necessary for the definition to be any good.  For example, suppose you're defining multiplication modulo $11$.  Observe that $6$ and $17$ are equivalent to each other modulo $11$.  Similarly $4$ and $37$ are equivalent.  So if I find $6\cdot4$ and also $17\cdot 37$, will those be equivalent?  Notice that the first is $24$ and that reduces to $2$ and the second is $629$ and that reduces to $2$.  If they didn't reduce to the same thing, then multiplication modulo $11$ would not be well defined.

**"Undefined"** refers to an expression, not to a value of an expression.  Thus "$20/4$" is an expression, and "$2+3$" is an expression, and they're two *different* expression, but both have the same *value*.  The expression "$0/0$" is also an expression, but it doesn't have a value.  Hence it is undefined.

What "defined" means **in general** is a tougher problem and I won't attempt to deal with it here unless the Muse get more emphatic.

Comment: Zero divided by zero does have a value. It can be any number - real, complex, or quaternion. $0/0$ is like asking "what number times 0 will equal 0"? Of course, all numbers satisfy that condition.

Comment: @LeeSleek No, division by zero is not defined.  The domain of the division operator on the real numbers (or on any field) consists only of pairs $(x,y)$ where $y$ is not equal to zero.  Saying it has a value that "can be any number" is problematic, in part because it would mean that the statement "0/0 = 1" _can_ be true and _can_ be false (presumably depending on context) however this statement has no free variables, so there is no way for its truth value to depend on external considerations.

Comment: @LeeSleek The notion that 0/0 is an indeterminate form that "can be anything" probably comes from the fact that for any real number $L$, there are sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ converging to zero such that the sequence of quotients $\{a_n/b_n\}$ converges to $L$.  However, to be precise one should note here that nothing is really being divided by zero -- rather, the point is that the limit of quotients is only the quotient of limits if both limits are defined, and the second limit is nonzero.  If you get "$0/0$" then you can try a different way that might lead to an actual answer.

Comment: It's rather beside the point, since you could just use $5/0$ instead.  Then someone could claim that is $\infty$ (not $+\infty$ and not $-\infty$, but a single $\infty$ that's at both ends of the line).  This is context-dependent.  But the point is that I explained what "undefined" means.